# MonoAlphabetic and PolyAlphabetic ciphers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, caesar-cipher

This code defines functions to cipher text with both mono-alphetic (Caesar) ciphers and poly-alphabetic ciphers. I also define a shortcut for rot13. I like this code and I think it is easy to read, but code is never perfect so I ask you for improvements.

```
import Data.Char (toLower)

alphabet :: String
alphabet = ['a'..'z']

generalShift :: String -> Int -> Char -> Char
generalShift alphabet 0 letter = letter
generalShift alphabet positions letter
  | letter == last alphabet = generalShift alphabet (positions - 1) (head alphabet)
  | otherwise = generalShift alphabet (positions - 1) (succ letter)

shift :: Int -> Char -> Char
shift = generalShift alphabet

clean :: String -> String
clean = filter (`elem` alphabet) . (map toLower)

monoAlphabeticCipher :: Int -> String -> String
monoAlphabeticCipher key = map (shift key) . clean

rot13 :: String -> String
rot13 = monoAlphabeticCipher 13

poliAlphabeticCipher :: [Int] -> String -> String
poliAlphabeticCipher keys text = zipWith shift keys (clean text)

main :: IO()
main = print $ poliAlphabeticCipher [3, 2, 1] "abc"
```

Answer (score 2):

## `generalShift`

Note the following about `generalShift`:

1. the `alphabet` argument never changes throughout the recursive calls
2. the only elements of `alphabet` accessed are the first and last characters
3. `last` is a potentially expensive function since it traverses the entire list to find the last element

To elaborate on point #2, note that the following calls are exactly the same:

```
generalShift "abcdefg...xyz" 10 'x'
generalShift "az" 10 'x'
```

Given these observations, why not just pass the first and last characters of the alphabet to `generalShift`, i.e.:

```
generalShift :: Char -> Char -> Int -> Char -> Char
generalShift firstChar lastChar positions letter = ...
```

## `elem`

`elem` is another potential expensive call. I would detect alphabetic characters using `<=` comparisons with the end points of the upper- and lowercase character ranges:

```
isAlphabetic ch = ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z') || ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z')

clean str = filter isAlphaBetic . map toLower
  -- or the other way around: map toLower . filter isAlphabetic
```

## more `generalShift`

There is a much faster way to compute the shift of a letter using the fact that Char is an enumeration (i.e. an instance of the Enum class) and therefore the following functions are available:

```
fromEnum :: Char -> Int
toEnum :: Int -> Char
```

These work like the `ord()` and `chr()` functions in other languages.

Let's assume the first and last characters of the alphabet are the standard `a` and `z`. I've leave you to figure out exactly what the code should look like, but here are some hints:

```
To shift a letter _n_ positions in the range a..z:

1. Determine how far away from 'a' the letter is.
2. Add n to that distance.
3. If the distance computed in step 2 would place it beyond 'z',
   subtract the number of characters between 'a' and 'z' and
   try again.
4. Add the distance computed in step 3 to the letter 'a'
   and return it as the encoded letter.
```

There will be a bunch of calls to `fromEnum` and `toEnum` as well as perhaps the `mod` function might help here.

## `poliAlphabeticCipher`

Nothing really wrong here, but I have a suggestion... it is customary to repeat the key if it isn't long enough for the entire message. I.e., if the key was `[3,2,1]` and the message was `"Hello"`, you would repeat the key as many times as was needed to cover every letter of the message. The key used to encode the message in this case would be `[3,2,1,3,2]`.

You can use the `cycle` function to repeat a list forever:

```
cycle :: [a] -> [a]
-- e.g. cycle [1,4,2] = [1,4,2,1,4,2,1,4,2,1,4,2...]
```

and then `polyiAlphabeticCipher` may be written as:

```
poliAlphabeticCipher keys text = zipWith shift (cycle keys) (clean text)
```

With that change `monoAlphabeticCipher` may be implemented using `poliAlphabeticCipher`:

```
monoAlphabeticCipher shift text = poliAlphabeticCipher [shift] text
```